# Display an error message when API is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have table data where I'm fetching that data through API. I need to display an error message on the user screen like  `something went wrong` message

I tried the below code

```js
const File history = () => {
   const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
   const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);
   const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
   const getFileHistoryData = async() => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("api");
      const data = await response.data;
      if (data.length > 0) {
        setTableData(response.data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
    }
  };
  const renderErrorMessage = () => {
    return(
      <div>
         {errorMessage !- & (
             <h1>{'Something went wrong: + errorMessage}</h1>
         }}
      </div>
    )
}
  return (
      <div>
         {this.renderErrorMessage()}
         <MyTableComponent/>
      </div>  
     );
}
```

How do I display the error in the frontend render the message since it's a functional component?

Comment: Well, the right way to do this would be on the UI component that is calling this function, in the catch block you can do setErrorMessage , just like your setTableData, and on the rendering, if errorMessage is there, show the H1 block as you did already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comment, you should change the function to store the error state, and change the rendering function to show that.

```
const File history = () => {
   const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
   const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);
   const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
   const getFileHistoryData = async() => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("api");
      const data = await response.data;
      setErrorMessage('');
      if (data.length > 0) {
        setTableData(response.data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
      setErrorMessage(e.message);
    }
  };
  const renderErrorMessage = () => {
    return(
      <div>
         {errorMessage !== '' && (
             <h1>{'Something went wrong: + errorMessage}</h1>
         }}
      </div>
    )
}
  return (
      <div>
         {renderErrorMessage()}
         <MyTableComponent/>
      </div>  
     );
}
```

Comment: You need to declare errorMessage using useState, just next to setTableData add;

const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState('');

this should do it.

Comment: I tried the above code and set the state too but still its not working can you check my code above

Comment: you missed out storing the error message, I just added that on top of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your code as such :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react',
import axios from 'axios',
import MyTableComponent from 'YOUR_PATH_TO_THIS_COMPONENT',

class File extends Component {
  state = {
    tableData : [],
    isVisible : true,
    errorMessage : '',
  }
  
  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios.get("api")
      .then(response => {
        const fileDataHistory = Object.values(response.data);
        if (data.length > 0) {
          this.setState({
            tableData:fileDataHistory,
          });
        }
      }
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({
          errorMessage:error,
        });
  };
  
  renderErrorMessage = () => {
    return(
      <div>
         {this.state.errorMessage !== '' &&
             <h1>{'Something went wrong:' + this.state.errorMessage}</h1>
         }
      </div>
    )
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         {this.renderErrorMessage()}
         <MyTableComponent/>
      </div> 
    )
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you check the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errorMessage') `

Comment: I just edited my post and transformed it from a function to a class which is easier to read and use. I added the required imports too

Answer (score 0):

You could use a state to store the error message when an error occurs and, use that value to display the error message. Instead of checking if the error message exists in the message rendering function, you could alternatively also use `&&` operator to render the message conditionally.

```
const File history = () => {
   const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
   const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);
   const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
   const getFileHistoryData = async() => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("api");
      const data = await response.data;
      setErrorMessage('');
      if (data.length > 0) {
        setTableData(response.data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
      setErrorMessage(e.message);
    }
  };
  const renderErrorMessage = () => {
    return(
      <div>
             <h1>{`Something went wrong: ${errorMessage}`}</h1>
      </div>
    )
}
  return (
      <div>
         {errorMessage.length && renderErrorMessage()}
         <MyTableComponent/>
      </div>  
     );
}
```